# Deshabilitar el back del explorador o reiniciar la página anterior

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario que al presionar el botón submit lo muestra en formato de reporte. Estoy buscando que al dar click atrás en el explorador el formulario lo reinicie. Actualmente me deja los valores pero ya genera un error en la llamada al servidor.

O simplemente deshabilitar el darle atrás. Encontré algo funcional pero ni idea de como aplicarlo, Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      onload = function () {
         var e = document.getElementById("refreshed");
         if (e.value == "no")
             e.value = "yes";
         else {
             e.value = "no";
             location.reload();
         }
     }</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes deshabilitar el retroceso con esta función, la colocas en el `<body onload="deshabilitaRetroceso()"></body>` espero te sirva.

```js
function deshabilitaRetroceso(){
    window.location.hash="no-back-button";
    window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button" //chrome
    window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="";}
}
```

```html
<body onload="deshabilitaRetroceso()">
```

Answer (score 0):

justo lo que buscaba, como apoyo a todos los compañeros que tienen una necesidad similar quedó de la siguiente manera.

Un archivo js (lo llame custom.js:

```
function nobackbutton()
{
   window.location.hash="no-back-button";
   window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button"
   window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}   
}
```

y en el head el siguiente código:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="nobackbutton();">
   </body>
</html>
```

TOTALMENTE FUNCIONAL. GRACIAS

Comment: No funciona bien